# an executable emits “pax archive volume change required”

Tags: linux, uid, pax

I'm trying to run a `./configure` executable for a software (I'm doing it through a remote Linux machine using PuTTY) and at some point it says:

```
ATTENTION! pax archive volume change required.
Ready for archive volume: 1
Input archive name or "." to quit pax.
Archive name >
```

So, I sent this warning to the makers of the software and they said the pax error is a result of my UID being greater than 21 bits. They suggested trying this prior to running `./configure`:

```
alias pax='/usr/bin/pax -O "S@'"
```

When I tried this it prompted me to enter something, of which I don't know what to enter.

I've looked online and couldn't find anything to resolve this. Can explain what's the meaning of pax? It's some kind of archive, but is it literally a folder on my file explorer or something?

Also the meaning of what I was sent by the developers "my UID is > 21 bits"?

Do I need to enter something for this pax or what will happen if I just quit? Seems like the software may not compile.

Any/all advice/tips would be greatly appreciated! I virtually have no software engineering experience, but learning!

Comment: In your alias, you're mixed up the quotes, you start with a single quote and end with a double quote.  Assuming everything else is correct, you'd want: `alias pax='/usr/bin/pax -O "S@"'` (ends with a double quote followed by a single quote).  I suspect the `S` should also be a `$` (`$@`).

Comment: "_it prompted me to enter something_" - what?

Comment: Related: [stackoverflow.com/questions/28450303](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28450303), regarding the "UID > 21 bits" 
 read the comment under the question and the [linked page](http://tinyurl.com/z8elmc6).

Comment: What is the output of `id -u`?

Comment: when i enter:
-bash-4.1$ % alias pax='/usr/bin/pax -O "S@"'
it says:
-bash: fg: %: no such job

but when I enter:
-bash-4.1$ alias pax='/usr/bin/pax -O "S@"'
it goes on to the next linke and no msg is displayed

then when I enter:
-bash-4.1$ ./configure
it starts configuring the software and then the same pax error arises.

can you please explain or any suggestions where i could learn about what all this means? alias? pax? archive? "$@"? /usr/bin/pax? -O?

Comment: This definitely is a bug in the software that is spread under the name "automake". A test that calls `tar` with options that are definitely inapropriate to `tar` is broken. A test that is not prepared to deal with the idiosyncratic behavior of mirbsd pax should be fixed. A test that in 2020  tries to enforce an archive format from 1988 should be revised. People who expect to only see GNU software on a computer cannot think outside the box. BTW: this test may succeed on SUSE Linux since this distro installs `star` as `pax` and thus does now run into that problem.

Answer (score 2):

The intent of this line is clearly that where the script calls the `pax` command, it behaves as though the script called it with the `-O` option. But there are several mistakes in this command. The correct command would be

```
alias pax='pax -O'
```

(Copy-paste, don't retype.)

Furthermore it won't help if you type it at your shell. It can only help if you put it in the `configure` script (and even there it may or may not help, but hopefully the developers were right that it would help). Insert it juts below the top line of the `configure` script, so that the script starts with the two lines

```
#!/bin/sh
alias pax='pax -O'
```

(The first line may be slightly different, e.g. `#! /bin/sh` or `#!/usr/bin/env sh` or `#!/bin/ksh` or variations.)

I don't know whether passing `-O` to pax will actually solve your problem. It tells pax to assume that the archive is a single volume, but that may result in data loss, because it won't help pax to parse the archive correctly.

The `pax` command is a utility to manipulate archives. Its archive format is (by default) one of the variants of the tar format. When pax writes an archive, if a file is owned by a user whose user id is greater than 2^21, it generates an extended header. The same applies to the owning group. Presumably the developer who suggested this workaround has analyzed that the `configure` script calls pax to generate an archive, then calls it again to read this archive, and when it reads it back, there is a bug related to extended headers.

You can check your user and group id with the command `id` at a shell prompt.

Comment: thank you so much for the information, putting this line below seemed to not signal the pax warning with the LOWERCASE o
alias pax='pax -o'
...with the uppercase O, like you put in your comment it gave the same pax warning.

Comment: @user422335 A lowercase o here wouldn't make any sense: after `-o`, pax expects the a list of keyword options. I don't know what this does, because it depends on how pax is called, but it's unlikely to do anything useful.

Comment: This is a problem that results from a broken `configure` implementation and the idiosyncratic behavior of the mirbsd pax implementation. Your proposal does nor fix the underlying problem, it just hides it. The `ustar` archive format has been defined in 1986 and finally accepted in 1988, but UNIX decided to support UIDs > 65536 with SVr4 and this happened starting from 1988.

Comment: @schily
if this is really only an issue with my UID, would I be able to just change my UID easily? i dont 100% understand your comment but I will do some research on it. Do you suggest any solutions for this particular case?

Comment: @user422335 Only the administrator can change UID. Such a large UID is somewhat uncommon, so you're probably on a system or network with a lot of users and the UID is out of your control.

Comment: @user422335 the problem is in an autoconf test that has been written by someone who misses the needed skills. This test likes to create create an `ustar` type archive but this archive type is so old that it does not support more than 21 bits in UIDs. The test on the other side has been written in a way that it triggers a problem in the local `pax` implementation on your system that creates an empty archive in your case. Another problem in your case is that your local `pax` does not behave correctly if it detects a logical EOF in the input archive. Instead of exiting, it asks for another medium

Answer (score -2):

If this is a UID issue then using

```
sudo ./configure
```

should fix the problem since the UID of root is 0 and only 1 bit.

Comment: Running as root seems like the worst possible workaround for this from a security perspective.

Comment: It is not an UID issue, but rather a bug in `configure` triggered by a user with a UID > 2097151.